# Need some help with Solidity Contract error

Tags: solidity, remix

*Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]*

Here's the solidity code. Can anyone please help me find the problem in the code?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa2ba735e2ff51fbaf9a3e12543bcd86be40e3a3d#code

Remix doesn't give any error while creating contract. The contract is deployed without any problem. When I try to send ether to get tokens it displays the error; *Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]*

Comment: Error details:   {
    "action": {
      "from": "xxx",
      "gas": "0x118992",
      "init": "",
      "value": "0x0"
    },
    "blockHash": "xxx",
    "blockNumber": 1562346,
    "result": {
      "address": "xxx",
      "code": "xxx",
      "gasUsed": "0x118991"
    },
    "subtraces": 0,
    "traceAddress": [],
    "transactionHash": "xxx",
    "transactionPosition": 3,
    "type": "create"
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your transactions and code, you are calling the fallback function `function ()` but your contract `SampleCrowdsaleToken` does not have one. Your contract is `Mintable`, `StandardToken`, `BasicToken`, `ERC20Basic`, `ERC20` (twice, because BasicToken is already a ERC20) and `Ownable`, but the only fallback function in your code is inside the `Crowdsale` contract.

Answer (score 0):

You deployed wrong contract.  `SimpleCrowdsaleToken` contract you are trying to buy tokens from is not a crowdsale contract, but rather a token contact.  You need to write another contract that inherits from `Crowdsale` and overrides `createTokenContract` method like this:

```solidity
contract SMTCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
  function SMTCrowdsale (uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, utin256 _rate, address _wallet) Crowdsale (_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet) {
  }

  function createTokenContract () internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return new SimpleCrowdsaleToken ();
  }
}
```